# A tuple and a tuple of predicates to boolean in Scala

Tags: scala, tuples, scala-3

Any idea on how to implement the following function in Scala 3?

I am okay with `inline` or not, and generally, a slight syntax change is ok (even macros are fine).
But I don't know how to do this without `asInstanceOf`.

```scala
type Pred[A] = A => Boolean

/** Computes values of predicates and combines them with `&&`.
  * 
  * The implementation does not use `asInstanceOf` or `isInstanceOf` */
inline def tupled[Args <: Tuple](inline preds: Tuple.Map[Args,Pred], inline args: Args): Boolean
```

Example:

```
val pred: (Int => Boolean, Int => Boolean) = (_ < 0, _ > 0)

println(tupled[(Int, Int)](pred)( 1, 2)) // should print false
println(tupled[(Int, Int)](pred)(-1, 2)) // should print true
```

Comment: What did you try so far? Why would you need `asInstanceOf`? Do you really need to work with tuples or a `List` would be okay?

Comment: @GaëlJ List would would require all predicates to work on the same `A`, I guess @Koosha needs something like `tupled((_.nonEmpty, _ > 0), ("string", 10))`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this one:

```
trait Reducer[Args <: Tuple, Preds <: Tuple]:
    def reduce(args: Args, preds: Preds): Boolean

object Reducer:
    given Reducer[EmptyTuple, EmptyTuple] = (args, preds) => true

    given [H, Args <: Tuple, Preds <: Tuple](using r: Reducer[Args, Preds]): Reducer[H *: Args, (H => Boolean) *: Preds] with
        def reduce(args: H *: Args, preds: (H => Boolean) *: Preds): Boolean = (args, preds) match
            case (ha *: ta, hp *: tp) => hp(ha) && r.reduce(ta, tp)

type Pred[A] = A => Boolean

/** Computes values of predicates and combines them with `&&`.
 *
 * The implementation does not use `asInstanceOf` or `isInstanceOf` */
def tupled[Args <: Tuple](preds: Tuple.Map[Args, Pred], args: Args)
                         (using r: Reducer[Args, Tuple.Map[Args, Pred]]): Boolean =
    r.reduce(args, preds)


scala> val pred: (Int => Boolean, Int => Boolean) = (_ < 0, _ > 0)
     |
     | println(tupled[(Int, Int)](pred, ( 1, 2))) // should print false
     | println(tupled[(Int, Int)](pred, (-1, 2)))
false
true
```

And we can ignore the type parameter if swap the arguments:

```
scala> def tupled2[Args <: Tuple](args: Args, preds: Tuple.Map[Args, Pred])
     |                          (using r: Reducer[Args, Tuple.Map[Args, Pred]]): Boolean =
     |     r.reduce(args, preds)
     |
def tupled2[Args <: Tuple](args: Args, preds: Tuple.Map[Args, Pred])(using r: Reducer[Args, Tuple.Map[Args, Pred]]): Boolean

scala> val pred: (Int => Boolean, Int => Boolean) = (_ < 0, _ > 0)
     |
     | println(tupled2(( 1, 2), pred)) // should print false
     | println(tupled2((-1, 2), pred))
```

Comment: Nice one! :) I had a quick look at the question this weekend but I was missing the "reduce" piece and decided not to press forward. I think it would be worth to get in touch with the Scala team to see whether they would consider including this in the standard library.